# Calculate the double integral $\iint_D f(x,y)dxdy$ in polar coordinates: $f(x, y)=\frac{x+y}{x^2+y^2}$, D: {$x^2+y^2≥-6y, x^2+y^2≤-8y; x≤0, y≤x$}

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

Calculate the double integral $\iint_D f(x,y)dxdy$ in polar coordinates:
$f(x, y)=\dfrac{x+y}{x^2+y^2}$, D: {$x^2+y^2\geq-6y, x^2+y^2\leq-8y; x\leq0, y\leq x$}

I switched to polar coordinates and got the following changes in region D:
$$r^2\geq −6r\sin(\theta) \implies r\geq−6\sin(\theta)$$
$$r^2\geq−8r\sin(\theta) \implies r\geq−8\sin(\theta)$$
$$\frac{\pi}{2}\leq\theta\leq\frac{3\pi}{2}$$
$$\sin(\theta)\leq\cos(\theta) \implies -\frac{3\pi}{4}\leq\theta\leq\frac{\pi}{4}$$

and in integrated fucntion:

$$\frac{x+y}{x^2+y^2} = \frac{\sin(\theta)+\cos(\theta)}{r}$$

And then I got double integral in polar coordinates:
$$∬f(x, y)dxdy = ∫_\frac{5\pi}{4}^\frac{3\pi}{2} ∫_{-6 \sin(\theta)}^{-8 \sin(\theta)} f(r \cos(\theta), r \sin(\theta)) r \, dr \, d\theta$$

Eventually I got the result of calculated double integral $-1-\frac{\pi}{4}$
I suppose, that's not the write answer, and I guess I'm mistaken in switching the region D. Can you please help me where is my mistake?

Comment: What makes you think your answer is wrong?

Comment: the answer just seems strange and wrong... and it's also negative, while all tasks in my uni always had positive result, that's why I'm kinda concerned. so you say that everything is okay?

Comment: Well, $D$ lies in the third quadrant, so $x+y<0$. The integrand is negative over $D$, so it's not unexpected that the overall result is negative.

Comment: I believe your answer is correct, yes.

Comment: thank you so much one more time! you helped me a lot